# Why does joined mesh appear colored?

Tags: sculpting

So I am watching a  "How to sculpt stylized character head" tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=usbupwLRENE). I joined neck and upper body together with ctrl + j.
[image: green neck]

After that, the neck is green in sculpt mode and the sculpting is odd, but why?
To try out anoter way I used the Bool Tool Add-On´s Union function. Than a box appears, indicating that the meshes didn´t realy merge.[image: cage]

When I merged meshes with the Bool Tool before the borders merged very fluently when sculpted on. That isn´t the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have painted *Face Sets* by accident, it's a kind of mask in *Sculpt* mode:

[image]

To remove them, go into the header menu *Face Sets > Initialize Face Sets > By Loose Parts*:

[image]

Comment: I don´t know how it happened. Pretty sure I didn´t use Face Sets. But your proposition worked.